# How do I set the Putty Window size to open bigger than the default?

Tags: windows, putty

I use Putty a lot and it always opens in quite a small window. I wondered if there were any parameters or settings I could change that could make it open in a window of different size by default.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you open PuTTY select **Window** in the tree on the left:

[image]

You can change the number of rows and columns in the Window here.

Alternatively, select **Appearance** and change the font size:

[image]

Once you're happy with your settings, select **Session** and then save these settings back as "Default Settings":

[image]

These settings will now be the default for new PuTTY windows.

Comment: Bad answer. He asked about window size, you gave him font settings.

Comment: @simontan You may have missed the very first part of the answer, where he points out the rows/cols setting, which controls the window size.

Comment: This isn't working for me in PuTTY 0.78.  This answer is 13 years old, but the screen shots look identical - think there's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the Columns from default 80 to 180, opened the session and it works.

Load the session
Under Category > Windows > Set the size of the windows > Columns > 180
Open the session.

I don't know if this is the proper way of doing it.